# How do i change my cardview background with a custom background?

Tags: java, android

I made a box.xml file and it looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#FF9800"></solid>
        <corners android:radius="10dp"></corners>
    </shape>
</item>

</selector>
```

For my cardview, I added `android:background="@drawable/box"` but the colour didn't change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cardview has is all include shape ,color,radius

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardElevation="10dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
        app:cardMaxElevation="12dp"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        >
```